# Numpy Sort Class Which Uses Dictionary Attributes

Tags: python, numpy

```
class Evaluations():
    columns = {0: "participationKey", 1: "focusKey"}
    participationKey = {"high": 3, "med": 2, "low": 1}
    focusKey = {"high": 3, "med": 2, "low": 1}

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def addData(self, participation, focus):
        self.data.append((participation focus))
```

If I bind the above class w/another function for example:

```
def bindClass()
    eval = Evaluations()
    eval.addData('high','high')
    eval.addData('low', 'low')
    eval.addData('med','med')
```

How would I sort the data using NumPy, then iterate to show results in print? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're storing your data in a list, I'm guessing it's not too huge, so Python's builtin `sorted` routine should do just fine; you probably don't need Numpy. I'm also assuming that you want to map the values stored in `data` using `participationKey` and/or `focusKey` for sorting. You could do something like

```
data = sorted(data, key=lambda pf: participationKey[pf[0]])
```

to sort by the mapped participation key. Or if you want to sort by the sum of the participation key and focus key

```
data = sorted(data, key=lambda pf: participationKey[pf[0]] + focusKey[pf[1]])
```

In these examples, you're passing the `sorted` function a "key", which is a callable function that maps list elements (in your case participation-focus pairs, which I've called `pf`) to numeric values that Python will sort in the way you want.

To iterate and print, just use a for loop

```
for pf in data:
    print "participation = %s, focus = %s" % pf
```

If you have to use Numpy, then you'll need to create a Numpy array of indices for sorting, then use `argsort` to get indices that will sort the data, then apply this back to `data`.

```
import numpy as np
inds = np.array([participationKey[pf[0]] for pf in data])
sort_inds = np.argsort(inds)
sorted_data = [data[ind] for ind in sort_inds]
```

Comment: Thanks I already know how to use sorted as such, but the challenge is to use NumPy just for learning purposes.

Comment: Numpy's `argsort` is what you're looking for. I've added an example, but most of the work is just converting to and from Numpy arrays.